# Using jQuery to add up values and then fire a result

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to take the different values in a list, add them up and if the values are greater than 150, a class is added to a specified div.  Here's the HTML I'm working with:

```
<ul class="fc_cart_item_options">
<li class="fc_cart_item_option fc_cart_item_weight">Weight: 70 <span class="fc_uom_weight">LBS</span></li>
<li class="fc_cart_item_option fc_cart_item_weight">Weight: 81 <span class="fc_uom_weight">LBS</span></li>
</ul>
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how, using jQuery, do I add up the values of these different list items shown above, and when they're greater than 150 to then add a class to a specific div?  There may be instances where I only have one list item that has a weight great than 150 whereas in some cases I may have 20 list items that add up to greater than 150 and therefore need the same outcome which is to add a class to a specific div.

My goal is that if the above list item's values is ever greater than 150, the div with the class of "gt_150" will get the class of "foo" added on.  Hope that makes sense.

======

Edit:

Just ran into a small problem after getting some great answers from others (thanks again so much everyone for your immediate responses).

One thing I didn't take into account is quantity.  Here's what I mean: a list item may be 70 pounds, but may have a quantity of 3 (210 pounds) which pushes it over the weight limit.  The problem is with the current solution, this doesn't take into account quantity of a given list item.  This solution (first response provided below) works great, but I forgot to factor the following.

```
<table>
<tr class="fc_cart_item">
<td>
    <ul class="fc_cart_item_options">
    <li class="fc_cart_item_option fc_cart_item_weight">
    Weight: 70 <span class="fc_uom_weight">LBS</span>
    </li>
    </ul>
</td>
<td class="fc_cart_item_quantity">3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In this HTML above, a list item may only be 70 pounds by itself (which doesn't cause the jQuery to add the class "foo" to the specific div), but if the quantity is 3, I need to factor that in.

In all cases with the list item, the next cell with the quantity will follow right after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.fc_cart_item').each(function() {
  var total = 0;
  $(this).find('.fc_cart_item_weight').each(function() {
     var weight = parseInt($(this).text().split(' ')[1]);
     total += weight;
  });

  var qty = parseInt($(this).find('.fc_cart_item_quantity').text());
  total *= qty;
  if(total > 150)
    $('.gt_150').addClass('foo');
});
```

Comment: i just implemented this and it worked great (thanks again so much!).  I just ran into 1 small problem that i'm going to post below.  if you could help, would love to buy you a beer! :)

Comment: @flinx777: I've edited to try and take into acount what you've added.

Comment: @sje397: wow...very nice.  that worked perfectly. let me do a little more testing on it, but right now it's spot on.  thank you so much!  case of beer coming! :)

Comment: ha - postage to Australia could be a bit much :)

Comment: yeh, i just opted for Paypal.  Not sure how much a case of beer cost there though :)  cheers!

Comment: wow i thought you were just kidding. you shouldn't have - but thanks

Comment: no problem...thank you!  i also sent you a follow up email...would like to chat some more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regexp to grab all the numbers in one go, and then calculate the sum:

```
var total = 0;
$.each($(".fc_cart_item_options").text().match(/\d+/g), function(i, v) {
   total += +v;
});

if (total > 150) $('.gt_150').addClass('foo');
```

Comment: interesting.  could you explain your use of "regexp" a little more?  i'm a total newb at JS programming and I'm curious why you suggest this.  Does it clear out text and just leave the numbers?

Comment: @flinx777 Sure. The idea of regexp (regular expressions) came about because programmers realised that they often needed to search for a particular pattern in text, for example finding a phone number in a paragraph. Regexp is a complicated set of symbols and rules that lets you specify exactly what you're looking for. The actual regexp that I used was `/\d+/g` which is saying, find me any digits in a row... i.e. a number. The reason I used this method is because it is flexible. As long as there is a number in your list, it will be found - it doesn't rely on the structure of `<li>` or `<span>`

Comment: @flinx777 continued... of course, often the structure is important, and can get you to the data you need more efficiently. They are two different approaches, if you know them both you can apply them as appropriate.

Comment: +1 on taking the time to give a thorough explanation. Well done.

Comment: thnx so much for the explanation...super helpful.